# Identifying unique Dataframe values r

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have two dataframes (`df1` and `df2`) with two columns each. The first column in both dataframes have the same values while the second column can be different. `df1` has ~3K rows and `df2` has ~13K rows. Using `df1` to validate against `df2` (since `df1` has 3K rows only) I am trying to identify and then write the column 1 and column 2 values from `df1` if column 2 value does not exist in `df2` (example follows) to a spreadsheet. I have no issues with the spreadsheet part.

Normally I would use a `while` loop but know there is a much better way in `r` for what I need. I have done a number of searches, looked through books etc just not finding it. Any advise is appreciated.

Example

| df1.col1 | df1.col2 | df2.col1 | df2.col2 | Write Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Coin_Value | .50cent | Coin_value | .50cent piece | No |
| Coin_Value | .10cent | Coin_Value | .50cent piece | Yes |
| Coin_Value | .10cent | Coin_value | .10cent | No |
| Coin_Value | .25cent | Coin_Value | Quarter | Yes |
| Currency | AUD | Currency | A$ | Yes |
| Currency | $$ | Currency | $ | No |
| Currency | $$ | Currency | Dollar | Yes |

Comment: u can do with base r `match()` ... df1[match(df1$col1,df2$col2),]

Comment: Thank you for the follow up and the answer.